# How can I bulk search and find data with slight differences in different rows?

Tags: search, text, find, bulk, emeditor

There is something I want to do; but i don't know if it is possible.
I want to know if I can do what I want to do with EmEditor or something else.

You can find an example of what I want below.

[Example Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDzrz.png):

• `The data on the left does not have the full name.`

• `The data on the right are those with the full name.`

**I present a small video to express what I want clearly.
Please watch the video first and then see the sample files where you can try how to do what I want.**

[Sample Video](https://disk.yandex.com.tr/i/F35Afhh_tSIP9Q)

[Sample Files](https://disk.yandex.com.tr/d/wzSS4-6m4AveJQ)

The file on the right contains much more data than the file on the left.
That's why the first thing that comes to mind is; so sorting is useless.

For example, the data in the 1st row of the data on the left; corresponds to row 2 of the data on the right.
So no one has the same row.
That's why sorting doesn't work; and I need to search the left side data one by one inside the right side data and find the full name.

**FOR INSTANCE:**

**On the left:** `10-infographic-solutions-part-1`

**On the right:** `10-infographic-solutions-part-1-D5DADA`

Instead of searching all of them one by one, I want to automatically find the left-hand data among the right-hand data.

I thought this might be possible with EmEditor; but I don't know how.
If this is possible I would like to know how.

Also, there is one more thing I want to know.
I have something to add to the end of each line; but I can't put a bulk cursor at the end of all of them.
How can I do this with EmEditor?

I hope I was able to express clearly what I wanted.
If there is anything that confuses you, please let me know.

Comment: It would be much easier to read/use samples in text rather than in pictures. Can you insert the sample in text in your question, please? The samples don't need to be real. Please simplify your samples. Also, I would like to know your expected result.

Comment: I have attached sample files and a small video for clarity.
You can watch the video and see what I want to do on the sample files.

Comment: I've noticed you are using an old version of EmEditor from your video. Please update to the latest version of EmEditor, which fixes many known bugs/issues from previous versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Advanced Filter** to find multiple strings combined with Logical Disjunction (`OR`). To do this:

1. Open `Missing Data.txt` with EmEditor, select all (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), and copy all the text to the Clipboard (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).
2. Open `Full Data.txt`, and click the `Advanced Filter` button on the `Filter` toolbar.
3. Click in the list box of the `Advanced Filter` dialog box, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the Clipboard contents to the list box.
4. While all the items in the list box are selected, make sure the `Match Case`, `(None)`, and `Logical Disjunction (OR)` options are selected, but no other options are selected.

[image: EmEditor - Advanced Filter]

5. Click the `Filter` button.

You didn't write what you want to do after searches, but if you want to remove all the matched lines from `Full Data.txt`:

6. Click the `Abort` button if you are already filtering. Click `Bookmark` button, and `Close` to dismiss the dialog box.
7. Right-click on the left edge of the editor (or select `Edit` menu - `Bookmarks`), and select `Delete Bookmarked Lines`.

As for selecting the end of each line, you can drag Mouse while pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> to make a zero-width vertical selection at right (or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd> to make a vertical selection, and press <kbd>End</kbd>). See [Multiple Selection Editing](https://www.emeditor.com/text-editor-features/coding/multiple-selection-editing/) for more information.

Comment: Excellent.
Thank you very much for the filtering feature. Now I can select them all and export them to a new `TXT` file.
Also the help you provided so that I could put a cursor at the end of them all worked.
Now I can select them all with `CTRL`+`A` and add cursors to all of them with `ALT`+`E`.
Thank you for your time and help.